# git search local history

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull

I made a couple commits without making a git push. After that I made a git push and know I can't find these commits that were only local. Can I somehow find those commits that I didn't push to remote repo?

Comment: A git push should have pushed all of your commits to the remote repo. Are you sure they haven't been pushed? You can check with git log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git log --oneline --all` to show all commits that are in your repo, even if they're not in the history of your current branch.

See also: [git log manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)